# MIP: Do binary variables perform better that integers?

Tags: time, allocation, computation

I have a model where investments can be done in blocks. Now I could model this with integer or binary variables.
Does anybody know which one is the better choice in terms of computational performance?

Edit: Its a gurobi model to solve a mixed interger linear programm so I define all variables in the beginning before handing it to the solver.

Comment: What do you mean by _"binary variables"_? It's all just groups of bits in the end.

Comment: Why is this tagged MIPS?